# How to run a bat script on multiple windows servers at once?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to run a .bat script that uninstall 32/64 bit agents and re-install 64-bit agents on almost 100 window servers.
Can you please guide me how this can be done?

I already tried running for one server to test

```
       psexec \\<windows server> -u <username> -p <password> <command>
```

But fails with error

```
 COULD NOT START PSEXESVC service on <windows server>
```

Do we need such service on all machines? Please suggest any other way?

Answer (score 0):

**PSEXEC is not a standard windows feature /service.**

If you wish to use PS Exec you will need to install it on all of the relevant systems first.

### Otherwise, your options are:

### CMD:

**A)** Does the "Agent" Installer you are using allow you to install / uninstall to a given server in it's command line syntax?

If so utilize that.

**B)** Put the Installer in central location (the Active Directory Netlogon Folder is great for this) along with a CMD script to run the uninstall and install processes.

Then Use SCHTasks to connect to each server and create a Scheduled task that runs using an administrative Username and password for that server, and set it to run with the highest privileges, set the action to be the path to the CMD script in netlogon that you have previously tested and nwo is working, set the task to run 1 minute in the future, or on demand (If on demand you then run schtasks again to execute the task).

### Powershell:

Work on getting a working CMD Script to run and use Invoke Command to run that command script on the remote systems.  As in Option B from CMD options you can keep the CMD script and Agent installer in the netlogon folder.